# What package does the system menu reside in?

Tags: 14.04, unity

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04LTS Server on an ESXi 5.5 host (VMWare). My boss wanted a GUI, so I installed ubuntu-desktop, without recommends to reduce the amount of extra stuff loaded on the server. It appears that there are missing packages for basic functionality though.

In the Status Menu at the top of the screen, I expect to find a gear (the system menu) with options to logoff, shutdown, restart, etc. That system menu is missing. What package does it reside in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [The Session Menu](https://launchpad.net/indicator-session), package `indicator-session`

Comment: Excelent, that is exactly what I was looking for